# convert categorical variables changed to numerical codes back to their original form

Tags: python, arrays, dataframe

I am working on creating a recommendation system and my data has one of its column as 'codeX'. codeX column includes product codes in the form 2278K, 5567H, 56738P etc. For creating sparse matrix i converted codeX column to numerical codes.
this is the code i used for conversion

```
`df['CodeX'] = df['CodeX'].astype("category")
 df['product_id']= df['StockCode'].cat.codes
```

Now after all other relevant calculations and fitting the model i get the recommendation for a set of user as below:

Each line in the result represents a list of recommended items for each user

```
recommendation =
array([[2733, 3145, 1019,  402, 2043],
       [2733,  886,  402,  797,  763],
       [1648, 2128, 3216,  797, 1934],
       ...,
       [2903, 1842, 1648, 1841, 1449],
       [1370, 2621,  672, 2440, 2517],
       [ 218, 2705,  809, 1813, 3087]], dtype=int32)
```

but i want my result to contain its original codes

```
array([[837Y, 73489U, ...],
       [2837B, 82381W, ...],
       ...,
       [2563Y,27487P, ...]])
```

I tried using lookup, so as to map values to their original form

`product_lookup= train_df[['product_id','CodeX']].drop_duplicates()
product_lookup['product_id']= product_lookup.product_id.astype(str)`

but still i am not able to get the results

i am completely new to python. Can someone guide me on how i can get my result in the desired format.

Comment: Can you give us some more info on the format you want? What does `2278k` and the like mean?

Comment: @ZacharyOldham `2278K`  and like are the  product codes and data is categorical, which i converted to numerical codes. now i want the result back in its original form(categorical)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
df['numcode']= df['CodeX'].astype("category").cat.codes
```

Instead of reformatting the existing column why not just make a new own? this way you keep the original values. The other option would be to make a dictionary and map output over to the dictionary values.

Comment: what does that dictionary look like now and then how are you trying to use it to map it over? Please show some output would be helpful

Comment: thanks!. Your answer helped me in reaching to the desired solution:)

Comment: Using `d=dict(enumerate(df['CodeX'].cat.categories))`  i got the dictionary {0: '1002FG', 1: '1012HG',...,..} and the output that i wanted to transform was stored in array 'recommendation'. I the used    `np.vectorize(d.get)(recommendation) `    and i finally see my output as                       
                                                           `array([['23284M', '22151L', ...],...
       
       
       ...,
       ['82583N', '85123AY', '21035O', '22151L', '16045M']],`